# Unity how to make a Visual JoyStick in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a script to put on a button that will detect a drag direction to move a player

```
void OnGUI()
{
    if (buttonRect.Contains(Event.current.mousePosition))
    {
        if (Event.current.type == EventType.MouseDown)
        {
            buttonPressed = true;
        }
        if (Event.current.type == EventType.MouseUp)
        {
            buttonPressed = false;
        }
    }
    if (buttonPressed && Event.current.type == EventType.MouseDrag)
    {

    }
}
```

If this script was to be placed on a button, how could I get the buttons bounds as a rectangle?

Also, If anyone has a better solution for controling movement by drag I would be open for suggestions.

Comment: OnGui should not be used for new development. It is only still there for debugging purposes and backward compatability in modern editions of unity. From [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GUIScriptingGuide.html): *"The IMGUI system is not generally intended to be used for normal in-game user interfaces that players might use and interact with"*

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks for the heads up.  Do you know how I could implement drag?

Comment: Not sure if it covers dragging, but here is [the tutorial on Button](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-button?playlist=17111) for the modern UI system.

Comment: Thanks I'll check this out

Comment: Are trying to make a visual joystick? Please explain more of what your are trying to do

Comment: Yeah I was trying to make a joystick

Comment: you **must not** use the old "ongui" system, it is now deprecated and does not work.  (Just use UI for your buttons etc - it is ridiculously easy.  Just click in the menu "add canvas" and then click "add button".)  Regarding your question it is a one billion times duplicate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement your own Visual Joystick by using the Unity new [event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41392130/3785314) callback functions such as `OnBeginDrag` `OnDrag` and the `OnEndDrag` function. There is a already made Visual Joystick package out there for Unity, so implementing your own is like reinventing the wheel.

All you have to do is to import the `CrossPlatformInputManager` package from Unity's [UnityStandardAssets](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/32351) then use `CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal")` and `CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")` to read the direction of the image/thumb.

To make one from scratch, you can flow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGYObojmkO4) video tutorial.

Comment: If you have time do you, know how to implement a cross playform swipe/drag across the joystick without initially clicking on it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a mobile solution that is really accurate and natural like a physical joystick, take a look at this asset:

[Ultra Precise D-Pad Joystick](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/ultra-precise-dpad-joystick-198066)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).