# Two scripts Input.GetMouseButton(0) in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two scripts like this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Object").transform.position.x > -1.9)
        {
            GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Object").transform.Translate(Vector2.left * szybkosc);
        }
    }
}
```

And second script is similiar, only there is "Vector2.right" difference. If I have one script, it works perfectly, but when I add second script, they doesn't work. I add these scripts to two different gameobjects.

Comment: Define "doesn't work" please.

Comment: When I click them, Object doesn't move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And second script is similiar, only there is "Vector2.right"
>   difference

That's the problem right there.

You are moving the object left with `("Object").transform.Translate(Vector2.left * szybkosc);`

then you have another script that is moving it right with `("Object").transform.Translate(Vector2.right * szybkosc);`.

What do you expect to happen? I think that the "Object" GameObject should remain still or even create a weird behavior. You can't be moving one Object to two opposite directions at the-same time.

Maybe the second script is supposed to be moving another GameObject `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("AnotherObject")` instead of the first GameObject the first script is already moving....

---

Not related to your problem but you should call `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag` once in the Start function.

```
GameObject objToMove;

void Start()
{
    objToMove = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Object");
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        if (objToMove.transform.position.x > -1.9)
        {
            objToMove.transform.Translate(Vector2.left * szybkosc);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

> I'm making control system. I have two arrows - left arrow and right
>   arrow. When I touch and hold left arrow, object moves left, when I
>   touch and hold right arrow, object moves right.

It's good to mention what you are doing in your question. This is what EventSystems is used for. `OnPointerClick`, `OnDrag` and `OnEndDrag` are used to make such things. You can find more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391708/how-to-detect-events-on-ui-and-gameobjects-with-the-new-eventsystem-api/41392130#41392130).

In fact, you need a [Visual Joystick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37626911/3785314). Use Unity's CrossPlatformInputManager from the Asset store and that should do it. It will save you so much time of having to make your own with `OnPointerClick` and `OnDrag` .

The value from `CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")` can then be used to move your Object left or right.

Comment: No, I'm making control system. I have two arrows - left arrow and right arrow. When I touch and hold left arrow, object moves left, when I touch and hold right arrow, object moves right.

Comment: **Yes**. My answer is telling you why it's not moving. Read that again. This is not how to detect touch on Objects. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391708/how-to-detect-events-on-ui-and-gameobjects-with-the-new-eventsystem-api/41392130#41392130) for how to do that.

Comment: What I think OPs issue is that he doesn't know that Input.GetMouseButton(0) doesn't care _where_ you click, only _that_ you have clicked, meaning every time you click (doesn't matter where) you will tell the object to move both left and right.

Comment: Yup that what I said in my answer. The thing is moving left and right at the-same time making it to remain still at the-same place. That's why I provided a link in the comment for how to detect touch on any object,

Comment: @Sleeper I noticed you use the `CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw` in your new question. Don't forget to accept answer if your issue is solved.

Comment: @Programmer done, if u can, please help me in my new question